# EventListener in every controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an Angular app use angular 1.7 and ui-router. In my index.html, I have `document.addEventListener('keyup',onKeyupVT)` - event never need remove. In every controller, I also have onkeyup Event (`document.addEventListener('keyup',onKeyup)`). I have a button in index.html (not in controller). If button toggle, I will add or remove onkeyup Event in controller (not in index.html).

I try `$rootScope.on('Event' + n, function(e,data){ //... })` in every controller and call `$rootScope.emit('Event' + n,data)`. It work but I need write it in every controller. So what Should I do. Thankyou for your help

Answer (score 0):

If a controller adds a document wide event listener, it needs to remove the listener when the controller is destroyed.

```
app.controller("ctrl", function($document) {
    $document.on("keyup",onKeyup);
    function onKeyup(ev) {
        console.log(ev);
    }

    //REMOVE event listeners
    this.$onDestroy = function () {
        $document.off("keyup",onKeyup);
    };
})
```

This is needed to prevent memory leaks and other unintended behavior.

Comment: good info, that is relevant to some degree; but, it doesn't exactly address the question and intent.  i.e. Are you suggesting O.P. continues to add the EventListener and Handler in every controller?  You see, the question is more of a inquiry on best practices with the intent to avoid boilerplate coding then anything else

Comment: @BrettCaswell Since the OP has not explained what he is doing with the event listener in each controller, it is difficult to recommend an alternative.