# removeEventListener in controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dom-events

I have a Angular app use angularJS v1.7 and angular-ui-router. In every controller, I have onkey event, and I have a modal menu in index.html. My problem is when modal show I need remove onkey event in controller and add my onkey Event in modal. I have very much controller in my app.

index.html

```
<body ng-app="app-demo">

    <a ui-sref="home">Go to HOME</a>

    <ui-view></ui-view>

    <div ng-controller="vt" style="position: fixed; right: 0; top: 0;">
        <div>Modal show: {{ vt }}</div>
    </div>


    <script>
        app.controller('vt', function($scope,$rootScope) {
            $scope.vt = false;

            function onKeyupVT() {
                $scope.vt = !$scope.vt;
                $scope.$apply();
            }

            document.addEventListener('keyup',onKeyupVT);
        });
    </script>
</body>
```

home.html

```
<div ng-controller="app-home">
    <h1>Home</h1>
    <button ng-click="goToSubPage()">Click me to view sub list.</button>
</div>

<div ui-view="list-1"></div>
<div ui-view="list-2"></div>
```

list-1.html

```
<div ng-controller="list-1">
    This is List - 1
</div>
```

homeController.js

```
app.controller('app-home', function($scope,$state) {

    $scope.goToSubPage = function() {
        $state.go('list-1');
    }

    function onKeyup() {
        console.log('Home');
    }

    document.addEventListener('keyup',onKeyup);
});
```

```
app.controller('list-1', function($scope,$stateParams) {
    function onKeyup() {
        console.log('list-1');
    }
    document.addEventListener('keyup',onKeyup);
});
```

What should I do. I'm very new in angularJS.

Comment: Are you using two accounts to post same question? See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56620073/eventlistener-in-every-controller/56621058#56621058

Comment: I want remove event when controller home and list-1 still show. It's don't work with my app.

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to create a service to delegate the `keyup` events:

```
app.service("keyupDelegate", function() {
    this.target = new EventTarget();
    this.disableDispatch = false;
    
    document.addEventListener("keyup", keyupHandler);

    function keyupHandler(event) {
        if (!this.disableDispatch) {
            this.target.dispatchEvent(event);
        };
    }
});
```

Then each view controller can use that as a target:

### View controller

```
app.controller('app-home', function(keyupDelegate) {

    // ...    

    function onKeyup() {
        console.log('Home');
    }

    keyupDelegate.target.addEventListener('keyup',onKeyup);

    this.$onDestroy(function() {
        keyupDelegate.target.removeEventListener("keyup",onKeyup);
    });
});
```

The modal controller can then disable the dispatch when it is active:

### Modal controller

```
app.controller("modal",function(keyupDelegate) {
    
    //...

    keyupDelegate.disableDispatch = true;

    this.$onDestroy(function() {
        keyupDelegate.disableDispatch = false;
    });
});
```

Comment: thanks for your help, I try and get Error: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'dispatchEvent' of undefined at HTMLDocument.keyupHandler"